# What's the name of this?

Tags: .net, .net-core, module, f#

I was looking for module defination (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/modules Under the "Recursive modules") and I saw:

```
module rec RecursiveModule =
    type Orientation = Up | Down
    type PeelState = Peeled | Unpeeled
```

I searched for "these" `type Orientation = Up | Down` and `type PeelState = Peeled | Unpeeled`. But I don't know the name of "these". Could someone say the name of "these"?

Sorry for tags pals!

Comment: Algebraic data types? Discriminated unions? In your particular case, could also be called "enumerations". Or, more generally, they're both "types".

Comment: Hey @FyodorSoikin! Thanks for help but enumerator are expressed like ```type MyEnum = | EnumTest1 | EnumTest2 | ...```. I'm confused.

Comment: That is exactly how they are expressed in your snippet. What differences do you see?

Comment: You should remove the recursion tag (for that matter, all tags except F#), because your question has nothing to do with recursion. For an introduction to the F# type system, it's hard to beat https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/understanding-fsharp-types/. See in particular #6 in that series about discriminated unions.

Comment: Thanks @FyodorSoikin! So, both of expressions are how enums are expressed. I got it.

Comment: @JimFoye I removed the "recursion" tag. I know this documents and the page you mentioned. I'll examine the page more carefully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"These" two types above are [discriminated unions (DU)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions).

[Enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/enumerations) have to declared with numbers, see:

```
type Color =
   | Red = 0
   | Green = 1
   | Blue = 2
```